# PriorityQueue throwing class cast exception

Tags: java, priority-queue, classcastexception, comparable

PriorityQueue add method throws class cast exception (MyVertex cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable) on executing.

Some Object of type MyVertex are inserted correctly, and some throws exception, couldn't manage to find the differences between them.

See the attached lines of code in java:

```
 PriorityQueue<Vertex> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
 for (Edge edge : vertex.getEdges()) {
      pq.add(edge.getTo());
 }
```

expected: The method pq.add() should not throw an exception.

Comment: is MyVertex implements Comparable?

Comment: See [`PriorityQueue.add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#add(E)): "Throws:
    ClassCastException - if the specified element cannot be compared with elements currently in this priority queue according to the priority queue's ordering" - show us your `MyVertex.compareTo`-implementation, seems you've got a bug in there.

Comment: Side note: you forgot the diamond in `new PriorityQueue<>();` - please don't use raw types.

Comment: I assume that `MyVertex` is a subclass/implementation of `Vertex`? Can there be other types of vertices returned by `edge.getTo()`?

Comment: @Hulk, First element will be added to `PriorityQueue` even if it doesn't implement `Comparable` since there are no other elements to compare to.

Comment: @Ivan yes, good point - I suspected a more subtle bug due to the "some [...] are inserted correctly" statement, but we won't know if "some" is >1 unless OP tells us more.

Comment: Does edge.getTo() return a subclass or implementation of Vertex ? If so, does Vertex implement CompareTo such that, the object being passed to CompareTo is cast to Vertex before the comparison is made ? If the compareTo is implemented in subclass, u may get a classcast exception as superclass cannot be cast to subclass type.

Comment: Hi, MyVertex is a simple POJO, not extending or implementing nothing.

Comment: The returned value of edge.getTo()  is MyVertex ( again simple POJO class, getTo() simply returns the field to), and the value was evaluated correctly while debugging(in both the correct behavior and the non-correct one).

Comment: @LiranSimanTov Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] including your classes, which can be compiled and tested by others, which throws an exception when you try to add a new entry to the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Implement `Comparable` interface and override `ComapareTo` inside `Vertex` class to satisfy the priority queue's ordering.

   As the java doc says - `add` *throws ClassCastException if the specified element cannot be compared with elements currently in this priority queue according to the priority queue's ordering*.
2. As you say it was working before, its because the add call will not throw the ClassCastException when the priorityQueues's size is 0 (when first element is added). To test that,  before the call to the for loop print the size of `vertex.getEdges().size()`. If the size appears to be greater than 0, thats when the `ClassCastException` will be thrown.

When size is not zero a sift-up operation is invoked as the underlying data_structure in the priority queue here is a heap.

The exception that you see is triggered from `sift-up`, as sift-up internally requires your elements to implement `Comparable`. And `sift-up` is called when the priority queue size is not 0, or a subsequent element is added.

**Note:**

- Heap should satisfy the heap property: if P is a parent node of C,
  then the key (the value) of P is either greater than or equal to (in
  a max heap) or less than or equal to (in a min heap) the key of C.

  sift-up: move a node up in the tree, as long as needed; used to
  restore heap condition after insertion. Called "sift" because node
  moves up the tree until it reaches the correct level, as in a sieve.

[Heap_data_structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure))